# Ionic Framework page redirection

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Can we develop multiple page application in an Ionic Framework. Like I want to consume a RESTful Webservice which has to get input from the form values and that values append to that URL and the response (data) has to display in other page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. The Ionic Framework uses something called `angular-ui-router`, which allows you to handle the routing necessary for multiple pages. You can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). There are some articles regarding the router, [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router) and [here](http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/).

I would recommend that you create the Ionic application using one of the following commands: `ionic start myApp sidemenu` or `ionic start myApp tabs` both of those projects will get you an application with multiple pages/views.